# Why doesn't Minecraft: Pocket Edition let me play?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I've made an account and everything but I can't move. I can't uninstall my game because I won't be able to get it back. Why can't I move away from spawn?

It says that I have to register and create a password but I already have both accounts for Mojang and the pocket edition on. My tablet is a Kobo arc. It has the new version from last year.

Comment: Aren't kobos, ebook readers?

Comment: Why can't you get it back? Did you obtain this copy illegitimately?

Comment: It would have been nice if you mentioned that you were trying to play multiplayer. Also, minecraft PE doesn't require you to sign up for a Mojang account. PE servers don't use your Mojang account for login. Just register a password. Mojang accounts are used for the PC edition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't move from spawn location](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/154786/cant-move-from-spawn-location)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're on a multiplayer server.

To get past this, you have to type "/register", then a space, followed by any password you'll remember. Once you do that, it'll say "you have been authenticated", and you're free to (metaphorically) run naked in the rain, which is actually rather overrated. You'll have to do this again for every different server you go on that asks you to do this. When re-joining, it'll ask you to login, so you do the same kind of thing, typing "/login", a space, and the password you typed in last time. After that, you can move around and do whatever.

If this is single-player, then I have no idea what the hell is going on, and that is something for Mojang to answer.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

you have to type /login password in chat

Comment: I don't understand the down vote, this is actually true!

Comment: @LameBrains My guess is because it isn't the same for all servers.