# Can't move from spawn location

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Why can't I leave my spawn location when I connect to a online game? Every time I connect to an online game and I try to move it keeps pulling me back to spawn location?

Answer (score 2):

You have to register with the server before you can move, as an [extra layer of security](http://www.curse.com/bukkit-plugins/minecraft/loginsecurity). Just invent a password for this server and type the command:

```
/register [your invented password]
```

Now your account on that server is locked with that password. Next time you connect you won't be able to move again until you do

```
/login [your invented password]
```

Comment: Some times its /register password password