# MCPE doesnt let me move in servers! I have no idea what to do

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

MCPE doesn't let me move in servers! I have no idea what to do. It tells me to login or register but I have no idea how to do that. I pretty much bought it for no reason! Someone please help. I tried putting /register and then my email and pass but I don't know!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't move from spawn location](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/154786/cant-move-from-spawn-location)

Answer (score 2):

When you register, type register without the slash. Then it'll ask for your E-mail. Just type it in by itself without slashes or the register command. Same with the password. No other players can see what you are typing when you're registering/logging in.

Comment: :) I'm glad it worked