# "You are not logged in" after joining a server. What?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I join a Minecraft PE server, it says I'm not logged in and I can't move. What's the deal here?!

The only thing I have in mind is that I don't have a Minecraft account on my computer, is that the reason?

Comment: Some servers require you to create an account to play on their server. Try /register. Also, look on their website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MCPE doesnt let me move in servers! I have no idea what to do](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/229404/mcpe-doesnt-let-me-move-in-servers-i-have-no-idea-what-to-do)

Answer (score 0):

Many minecraft PE servers have certain plugins that force the player to "Login" to the server. This is to prevent any harm to the server, as certain players will have operator permissions. The reason for this is that minecraft PE allows you to have any name of your choice.

As already mentioned by angussidney, you can simply dash in the '/register' command. Be aware that some of these login plugins are very dodgy, and many allow the server owners to view entered passwords. So make sure that you don't list anything important.